# How install LINQ Preview May 2006 on windows 7?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linq, windows-7

I have Visual Studio web developer Addison , Visual Basic 2005 Express Edition, Visual C# 2005 Express Edition and Visual Web Developer 2005 Express Edition installed on my system.

My operative system is a Windows 7

When I start the installation of "LINQ Preview (May 2006).msi", I get the next error message: "Cannot find a valid Product to install LINQ with".
I click in the Accept button and get a second message: "You must have either Visual Studio 2005, Visual Basic 2005, Visual C# 2005 or Visual Web Developer 2005 installed before installing Microsoft .NET LINQ Preview (May 2006) Do you want to download Visual Studio 2005 Express Editions now?"

Comment: Do you have a good reason to want the LINQ preview? You'll probably find it far easier to just install VS 2008 (express) which comes with the released version of LINQ.

Comment: But there is no asp.net templates in vs 2008

Comment: @SmartestVEGA: Then your quesition is "what do I use instead of asp.net templates in VS08" ?

Comment: Hey - you really should answer the comments. Otherwise the fact that hyou don't, together with the lack of accepts will mean you keep getting less and worse answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not install the 2008 express editions? They have LINQ built in [and hence dont require previews]. Is there something specific about the preview bits you're interested in examining?

Comment: i am trying to compile the source of this project !!

Comment: Why? What are you looking to achieve? (As Simon P Stevens asked) The LINQ preview doesn't have source? Can you clarify what you want to compile and what your end goal is? If you can, then people shoould be able to point you in a useful direction.